# Generating an EER diagram in a diffable format programmatically in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, erd

I realize that an EER diagram can be generated in MySQL Workbench by following the steps under **Database > Reverse Engineer** (or command-R for Mac). It can then be exported as a PNG, SVG etc.

Is there a way to programmatically call this and can I generate an EER diagram in a format that can be diffable for commits? (text based or xml or something of that nature)

If we can, is it possible to generate the graphical view from the text format?

Comment: Download the source https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench and hook the function you need.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench is a (fat) GUI application and not made to be controlled by scripts or similar. I assume that's what you mean by "programmatically call this".

The problem of comparing models is completely different. A model file (.mwb) is essentially a .zip file. Rename it and you can unzip it. It contains an xml file with the actual model plus some additional data (images, an sqlite DB for table inserts etc.). The bad news is that the xml is not directly comparable as it contains memory references as unique IDs (which of course change whenever you save the model). If you can ignore these references you should be able to diff models, however.